# Weird Wine Packages w/ Weird Names - Can't Remove

Tags: apt, wine, uninstall

So I tried to install some stupid game through Wine but the game is not originally in English and some weird things happened. Now I am stuck with these "apps" that go nowhere (it was unable to open - something about the language switch). I have uninstalled everything to do with Wine via Synaptic Package Manager, but these 4 do not show up in that. I have also tried removing them via the terminal but it will not remove them because of the file name or something, and it keeps saying it can't find the file. I would really like to get rid or these for real if anybody knows how. They also show up under Applications -> Other.

[Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANsvd.png)

Comment: If you open `/usr/share/applications` in your file manager, do you see them there? Or maybe in `/usr/local/share/applications` or in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: Nope, they didn't show up in any of those places. :/